# Is json tag in struct really necessary for marshaling?

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I was interested to learn if there is a way to have this:

```
type Example struct {
  Name    string   `json:"name"`
  Value   string   `json:"value"`
}
```

become this:

```
type Example struct {
  Name    string
  Value   string
}
```

and still allow for JSON marhaling/unmarshaling? Is there a library or a way to automatically assume or inject these tags without having to be explicit in every struct field?

Comment: Just give it a try, `encoding/json` works without tags as well. (and your tags are invalid anyway)

Comment: You may omit tags, but it is not recommended to do so, as it takes the field's name as-is ("Name" and "Value"). Consider the repercussions of suddenly deciding to rename a struct field. With no tags, you've just changed the `json` output. With tags, the `json` stays the same. Also note that fields must be exported, and uppercase `json` fields is unconventional.

Comment: There isn't a library that can automatically look for "Name" or "name" when the struct field is "Name"? Libraries like Java Spring do this for you automatically. This really can't be done in golang?

Comment: @Dan as I've already mentioned in my previous comment, `encoding/json` does what you want, at least as far as I understand your question (https://play.golang.com/p/8HpPv_4fXGu). When it comes to *marshaling* it translates the fields verbatim, which is only logical since there's no "guide" other than the field name by which to decide how to generate the json. Also the fact that what you want works for unmarshal is mentioned in the package's documentation. (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)

Comment: @Dan also note that questions seeking recommendations for libraries, books, etc. are off-topic on SO, if you don't want to use `encoding/json` but you want to find a library that does "automatically" what you want it to do, you should try another venue.

Answer (score 0):

By default it will be encoded as

```
{ 
    "Name": "",
    "Value": ""
}
```

But go is writen on go and if you really really want lowercase without tags, you can just 'fork' `encoding/json` package, recreate it as your own package and change behavior in `encode.go` (line 1151 in go 1.13):

```
// Record found field and index sequence.    
if name != "" || !sf.Anonymous || ft.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        tagged := name != ""
        if name == "" {
           name = sf.Name <-- here, for example to strings.ToLower(sf.Name)
        }
        ....
```

I not recommend you to do that, but it works :)

Comment: I'm not looking for something hacky but more of an official library or framework that can automatifcally try to serialize an object based on its name. For example if I have a field "Value" in my struct, it can't automatically look for "Value" or "value" in the JSON object and try to associate it without me being explicit?